# Count polygons that intersects polygon in Spatialite

Tags: spatialite, st-intersects

I am trying to do a very simple query, but keep getting an error. I am looking to get the count of polygons that intersect with another polygon. I've used the following query:

```
SELECT feature__1 AS type, Count(feature__1) AS type_cnt
FROM cityprj_munparcel
WHERE (SELECT ST_Intersects(cityprj_munparcel.geom, to_districts.geom))
GROUP BY type
```

But keep getting the following error: no such column: to_districts.geom

I have looked at the table and have performed other queries with the layer and the the column is there. Unsure what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a WAG, but it looks like you need to: a) reference the to_districts table in a FROM clause; b) scratch the incomplete subquery; and c) specify the truth of the (boolean) ST_INTERSECTS condition. Maybe something like...

```
SELECT a.feature__1 AS type, Count(a.feature__1) AS type_cnt
FROM cityprj_munparcel AS a, to_districts AS b
WHERE ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom) = 1
GROUP BY type
```

Hope that helps--or gets you closer!